# What happened when block is declared as assign

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been a while not tweaking blocks. Today I found one interview question about block in Objective-C:

Giving below code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender;

@property(nonatomic, assign) void(^block)();

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int value = 10;
    void(^blockC)() = ^{
        NSLog(@"just a block === %d", value);
    };

    NSLog(@"%@", blockC);
    _block = blockC;

}

- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Log:%@", _block);
}
```

What would happen?

Here's the output and some debug value:

If I add a breakpoint at the end of `viewDidLoad()`, here is the output:

```
2017-08-03 14:28:49.209 TestApp[23692:1211863] <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x600000055210>
(lldb) po _block
0x00000001026b86c0
```

And after I click the button and break at `NSLog(@"Log:%@", _block);`, it shows:

```
2017-08-03 14:30:57.948 TestApp[23692:1211863] Log:{(
    _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc40b70cd10.minY{id: 16}
)}
(lldb) po _block
0x0000000000000003
```

So I kind of know that since `blockC` is freed after `viewDidLoad()`, `_block` should be pointing to a dirty field and cause memory leak or stack overflow. But what confuses me is that, first, in `viewDidLoad()`, why the NSLog output is `<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x600000055210>`, but the `_block` value is `0x00000001026b86c0`? Does this mean whatever on `0x00000001026b86c0` is a pointer pointing to `<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x600000055210>`?

Secondly, when we click the button, why `_block` becomes `0x0000000000000003`? It's not this value every time, sometimes could be `0x0000000000000001` and even other large numbers(or address value). Also how can NSLog output can be

> Log:{(
>           _UILayoutGuide:0x7fc40b70cd10.minY{id: 16}?
>       )}

Can someone help explain the whole process? Thank in advance!

Comment: Could you please check  `po _block` after the  `[super viewDidLoad]` is it showing `0x0000000000000001`

Comment: I think no. before assigning `blockC`, it should be nil

Comment: Because of `_block` is a dangling pointer after `viewDidLoad` you should better use the format `%p` instead of `%@`. The latter one will call `description` to `_block` which could lead to surprising results.

Comment: @macmoonshine you re right, I forgot %p format.. It makes sense now. One more question, how `assign` in this case works for block type?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but I think you will get a dangling pointer. Using `weak` will avoid the dangling pointer, but discard the block, too. `strong` is dangerous, because you have to copy a block when you will execute it after leaving its defining scope. Thus, the only valid storage type for blocks is `copy`.